# unwanted result with loops in c

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

In the following code no matter what I do it loops forever and showing "syntax error" forever.

This code needs to check if the answer is neither 'y' nor 'n'.  If it is ask again for answer and then if answer 'y' it will loop again all the func
and if answer is 'n' it should do nothing...

```
char answer = ' ';
int round = 0;
do
{
    round = chooseLevel();
    guess(round);
    while ((answer != 'y') || (answer != 'n'))
    {
        printf("\nWould you like to play again? (y/n): ");
        answer  = getch();
        putch(answer );
        printf ("\nchar is %c\n", answer );
        if ((answer != 'y') || (answer != 'n'))
        {
            printf("Syntax Error");
        }
    }
}
while (answer  == 'y');
```

Comment: That's now how you should use the phrase "Syntax Error". Such an error is when there's a flaw in your code (a missing `{`, `,`, `;` or `]` for example).

Comment: @Mast : "syntax" has broader meaning that just referring to code, and can apply to natural language also, or as Yoda's tortured syntax would have it *"to natural language apply it may"*.  However you are correct in that the term it is inappropriate in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition should be with `&&` and not `||` :

```
(answer != 'y') && (answer != 'n')
```

The `answer` cannot be both 'y' and 'n', so either `answer != 'y'` or `answer != 'n'` will be true. In case of `||` the whole statement will become `true`.

```
True || False => True
```

Comment: Or the equivalent `!(answer == 'y' || answer == 'n')` if you prefer.  (DeMorgan's Theorem)

Answer (score 3):

Switch `||` to `&&`. Currently, if `answer` is `y`, both `if` and `while` conditions will evaluate to `('y' != 'y') || ('y' != 'n')` or `(false) || (true) = true`. The only way to get out of the while loop is to have `answer` somehow equal to both `y` and `n` at the same time.